# why is gmail auto adding a deal badge to my email without manual annotation

Tags: gmail, gmail-promo-tab

When sending a marketing message, my message is automatically getting a "deal badge" (e.g. 50% off in green) in the promotions tab without me explicitly adding annotation(s).

The offer in the deal badge is incorrect (assuming gmail is **scraping** for the details), so the "automatic" nature of it is sending the incorrect message to the recipient.

expectations are only the SL and from (possibly logo or letter in the oval) but NO other promotion tab elements.

Comment: Maybe try bolding your promotion and keep the sentences short and sweet. https://developers.google.com/gmail/promotab/best-practices#deal_badge

Comment: @Lex Not sure if I follow.  I'm not declaring anything in my code that should even make the deal badge display.

Comment: If you have code, sharing it could be helpful

Comment: that's the thing, the code that makes the "deal badge" forcefully show up (from us) is not present.  It has not been coded into the html at all.

Answer (score 0):

If an email is not annotated and is featured in the top bundle, then it can pull in deal badges. The only way to control and enrich your email is to add the annotation.

The annotation allows you to optimize on this prime real-estate by adding (and controlling) custom logo, badges, images, and more to drive your goals. Since the implementation is designed to be templatized, using information already within your email with little effort.

The [script tag](https://developers.google.com/gmail/promotab/overview) can be added to the head of your email template(s), you can customize the 5 features for the campaign (can be populated with merges, variables or dynamically - should be similar to your current creation process), and then you are all set. For the images, the goal was that you could use the same imagery from the body of your emails (brands have different ways of handling this, such as having a version of the image in the email body made at 538x138). However, **all the information for the enriched preview is information already in your email**. Mix and match the features to create the best enriched preview to drive your goals (if not using a feature, leave blank).

[Annotation features](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R1to3.png)